# How to create a page like the WordPress Plugin page

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I'm pretty sure this is basic but it's been a couple of weeks I'm struggling.

I'm building a video game news type of website with Wordpress and I would like the "game sheet" to work in the same way the WordPress plugin page works (here is an example: http://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/ )

The idea would be to have a page for each game and then this page would pull out content in each tabs to display different content:

- News would be articles with the game name as a tag
- Screeshots would be images from the media manager I would have tagged with the name of the game
- Game review and user voting in the sidebar
- etc...

Again, this seem to be a very basic taxonomy/custom post type system but I just don't know where to start and I can't find the right words to explain it to do a proper google search.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to create a "custom post type". In other words, something like a post, but with more / different fields. I suggest you use the plugin: "[custom content type manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/)".

After you create the custom post type you need, you will only have to create a page / post the summarizes the custom content you have built. For that you will also use the same plugin.

Comment: Thank you Ghuerren, I'm going to have a look at this plugin which seems to be doing what I need :)

Comment: I'm have a play around with the plugin and it getting there.

I'm trying to assign news to a "game" but I think this is where I'm lost. Should my games be part of the taxonomy or actually custom posts?


Ideally I'd like to have a game sheet which would pulled out all items (news, screenshots, videos, reviews...) which would use the same (tag?) as the game sheet.

Or is it the other way around. The taxonomy is actually my game sheet and I have to add field to it to then display its content.

I think I have the tools now I'm just missing the methodology to start it properly

Comment: good to hear. the best for you would be to create a custom type called games. then u create all the fields u gonna need: media (for screens), text area (for review), link (for the game ofical page), and so on. Note that u still have the categories after u create the custom content. u can use the categories to separate genres (action, shoot, kids, etc).